# Predicting survival within time (cumulative hazard)

Tags: r, linear-regression, cox-regression

By using R, how can one develop an **index score for predicting patient overall survival (OS)**?

I have a shortlist of 4 candidate predictors that showed to be associate with OS. They resulted from Cox multivariate regression (run with `coxph()`). The predictors are protein levels, hence they are all continuous variables.

The data table looks something like this (showing only n=10 here):

```
          days Status    Prot1   Prot13    Prot7   Prot21
Subj_1  115.69      0 2.284498 6.319168 6.070115 8.457412
Subj_2   72.30      1 2.473034 6.066573 6.140178 8.225987
Subj_3    1.08      1 2.662481 6.212845 6.971018 8.128949
Subj_4   69.63      1 2.761391 5.902610 6.433883 7.876319
Subj_5   78.41      1 3.038122 6.355257 6.852981 7.500973
Subj_6   42.90      1 2.058549 6.020681 7.231307 8.164025
Subj_7   31.00      1 2.305096 5.415107 8.126941 8.566320
Subj_8   51.12      1 2.931978 5.574601 7.503275 7.529957
Subj_9   11.01      1 2.218814 6.270222 6.710297 8.193895
Subj_10  27.68      1 2.821947 6.132379 6.911071 8.428218
```

The question is: **How can I create a formula which is capable to classify these patients into 2 groups: a group where the estimated survival is <60% in a 1-year period, and another which will include those with estimated survival> 60% in the same time period?**

Would there be any `function()` in R that deals with that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should post this question here

```
https://stats.stackexchange.com
```

since it is a matter of statistics. Anyway, you could try with a binomial regression to start, but there are many other models you could try. how many subjects do you have?

Comment: Thank you, @Carbo. I will post that question there. Any variation of binomial regression in particular? Also, what would be the binomial response you are thinking about? There are 200 subjects.

Comment: Oh, I had posted a variation of that question [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439074/defining-an-applicable-score-index-for-patient-survival-prediction), which was more focused on the formula in itself. I posted here to learn whether there is a R function to resolve this problem.

Comment: You welcome. You could try with a Naive Bayes classifier, Binomial regression (logic and profit). Here you can find some others you can apply in R https://data-flair.training/blogs/classification-in-r/  or this https://boostedml.com/2019/06/binary-classification-in-r-logistic-regression-probit-regression-and-more.html . I would suggest you to google binary classification in R and look for some of the results. there are a lot of sources and pages online that might help you building your classifier